# Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Tags: php

Im developed PHP user login and registration system, i have a displayed  always this error in my local host , how to fix it?

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
>   (C:\wamp\www\registerations\db.php on line 9)

this is my code
db.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('register');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: The error speaks for itself

Comment: Please, please please - *search* before asking another question.

Comment: @DirtyBit not really. There are lots of different PHP manager platforms. How do you install mysqli in arbitrary managed environments? How do you port the calls? There are a few stages to negotiate and some of them are showstoppers. E.g. environments where PHP modules aren't installable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","register");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

// try this..

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're still struggling, this is what you should be looking into:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'your_username_here', 'your_password_here', 'your_db_name_here');


if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)